# How do I get an IResource from an IEditorActionDelegate

Tags: delegates, selection, markers, eclipse-plugin, compilationunit

I wrote an IEditorActionDelegate to fire from a context menu on a CompilationUnitEditor. From there I want to create a marker at the start line of the selected text. I have an ITextSelection, and an IEditorPart object. How can I get an IResource from those so that I can call resource.createMarker()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can look at how Eclipse does something similar in its [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/EditorUtility.java.htm) class.

You can see ([line 222 and following](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/EditorUtility.java.htm#ixzz0fmAhVV1t)) it:

```
final IEditorInput  input= editor.getEditorInput();
marker= ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile().createMarker(IMarker.TEXT);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, offset);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, offset + length);
```

With `offset` and `length` something you should be able to infer from your `TextSelection`.